# NO Invalid mailbox name IMAP

Tags: postfix, imap, courier-imap

I want to create a folder named "spam" for my local mail server. But it throws this error

After running, **telnet localhost imap** and logging in

```
list "" *

 * LIST (\HasNoChildren) "." "INBOX.mu-prop"
 * LIST (\Marked \HasChildren) "." "INBOX"

create spam

NO Invalid mailbox name
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
create INBOX.spam
```

Your IMAP server is expecting all folders to have the INBOX prefix.

Comment: can i remove this INBOX prefix?